# How to get interface in the android backend from libgdx core?

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx

I would like to access the method in the core libgdx from android backend, but I faced difficulties.
I tried to make circular dependency between modules 'android' and 'core', but i faced with errors:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':android@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :android.
```

How to resolve that problem? And what is the best solution for that?

Comment: Please show a [mcve] that produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolve this by removing the cyclic redundancy you created. Instead call a method in your core project that executes the method from the "core libgdx". You can access your core project by saving the Game or Application class when your AndroidLauncher creates it.